# Xamarin Forms - GetBindingExpression

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xamarin.forms

In Silverlight (and other XAML based technologies) there is a method called GetBindingExpression which allows us to check what binding there is on a given dependency property. The method is on FrameworkElement so every single control gives us access to the binding expression.

For example:

```
var selectedItemBindingExpression = GetBindingExpression(SelectedItemProperty);
```

But, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in Xamarin Forms. Is there a way to get a binding expression from a BindableProperty property in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe there are any public APIs available in `Xamarin.Forms` to access to the `BindingExpression` - but you can use reflection to access the associated `Binding` and thus the `BindingExpression`

```
public static class BindingObjectExtensions
{
    public static Binding GetBinding(this BindableObject self, BindableProperty property)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(BindableObject).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetContext");
        var context = methodInfo?.Invoke(self, new[] { property });

        var propertyInfo = context?.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("Binding");
        return propertyInfo?.GetValue(context) as Binding;
    }

    public static object GetBindingExpression(this Binding self)
    {
        var fieldInfo = self?.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("_expression");
        return fieldInfo?.GetValue(self);
    }
}
```

**Sample usage - Get binding-expression**

```
var expr = this.GetBinding(TextProperty).GetBindingExpression();
```

**Sample usage - Get binding path (update 07/27)**

```
//to access path - you can directly use the binding object
var binding = this.GetBinding(TextProperty);
var path = binding?.Path;
```

Comment: Excellent. I've done this type of thing before. The Xamarin team likes to hide stuff from us for no reason.

Comment: Will test this out.

Comment: Maybe add a bit to explain how to get the BindableProperty? For anyone looking it's from the static Entry like _associatedObject.GetBinding(Entry.TextProperty)

Answer (score 1):

Improved Sharada Gururaj's solution:

```
public static class BindingObjectExtensions
{
    private static MethodInfo _bindablePropertyGetContextMethodInfo = typeof(BindableObject).GetMethod("GetContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    private static FieldInfo _bindablePropertyContextBindingFieldInfo;

    public static Binding GetBinding(this BindableObject bindableObject, BindableProperty bindableProperty)
    {
        object bindablePropertyContext = _bindablePropertyGetContextMethodInfo.Invoke(bindableObject, new[] { bindableProperty });

        if (bindablePropertyContext != null)
        {
            FieldInfo propertyInfo = _bindablePropertyContextBindingFieldInfo = 
                _bindablePropertyContextBindingFieldInfo ?? 
                    bindablePropertyContext.GetType().GetField("Binding");

            return (Binding) propertyInfo.GetValue(bindablePropertyContext);
        }

        return null; 
}
```

My solution has following improvements:

1. Caching of objects obtained by reflection (improves performance)
2. Removed unnecessary null checks
3. Use of reflection directly, the use of IntrospectionExtensions is
   unnecessary
4. GetBindingExpression method is not needed (all information about the
   binding can be retrieved from the Binding class)

Comment: Hi Igor, Welcome to StackOverflow, do you think you could add some explanation as to why this answer is an improvement? Does it use newer APIs, provide more functionality etc.

Comment: Hi  sedders123, my solution has following improvements
1) Caching of objects obtained by reflection (improves perfamance)

Comment: 2) I removed unnessary null checks
3) I use reflection directy, using of IntrospectionExtensions is unnessary
4) GetBindingExpression method is not needed  (all information about binding can be retrived from Binding class)

Comment: Fantastic :) Could you edit your answer to include this information? Adding it to the answer ensures that future users can easily see why this is a different and potentially better solution than any of the other answers.